# Flexslider whitespace

Tags: javascript, flexslider, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I am currently using Skeleton platform, and on it I've installed the Flex slider. There's a problem that bothers me, whenever I start my page, the slider creates a line of maybe 3-4 pixels in height at the bottom area of the slider. I've searched everywhere, people's suggestion was to set flex's margins to 0, but that didnt help.

Here's my code that starts flex:

```
$(window).load(function() {
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
  animation: "slide",
  directionNav: false,
  controlNav: true, 
  pauseOnHover: true,
  start: function(slider) {
    $('.total-slides').text(slider.count);
  },
  after: function(slider) {
    $('.current-slide').text(slider.currentSlide);
  }
}); });
```

And an image preview of the situation/problem.

[image]

Never mind the black space, I've created it on purpose to see if my image height was too small.

If you need a sample of the code, I will supply it.

Thanks in advance,
George.

Comment: What is the "Skeleton Platform"?  Your code does not look like ActionScript code, are you sure you meant to tag this with Flex, the Adobe/Apache UI Framework?

Comment: Skeleton is a grid based system, (http://www.getskeleton.com/). The code up there is a JavaScript one, had some troubles formatting it.

Comment: I retagged your question for you.

Comment: Thanks, really new on stackoverflow.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, then!  Be sure to check out the help section to help get yourself acquainted with the site: http://stackoverflow.com/help .  I think the question is written well enough so hopefully someone more knowledgeable than I can chime in.